# Angular2 POST call removes the Content Type and Body when examined in Fiddler

Tags: angular, post, fiddler

This is my client side Angular2 Code.

```
public getOutletsAndBizInfos(agencyId: number, locationId: number): Promise<BizAssignInfoPack> {

    let payLoad: any = { AgencyId: agencyId, LocationId: locationId };
    let hdLClientPack: HdLClientPack = new HdLClientPack(payLoad, HdLCommands.GetBizAssignOutlets);
    let bodyContent = JSON.stringify(hdLClientPack);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json' );
    let urlValue = Config.GetSrvBizAssignUrl();
    let reqOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers , body: bodyContent, url: urlValue, method: RequestMethod.Post });
    return this.http.post(urlValue, bodyContent , reqOptions)
        .toPromise()
        .then(result => {
            // alert("Got data from server.");
            let payLoad = result.json().payLoad;
            let payLoadContent = JSON.parse(payLoad);
            return payLoadContent;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

When I examine the request in the Fiddler, the header and body are missing. These are the Raw contents from Fiddler.

===============

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8012/api/srvbizassign/GetOutlets HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8012
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8    

HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

===============

Not sure what I am missing. Any advise please ?

Comment: dont do this  let bodyContent = JSON.stringify(hdLClientPack); only do this  let bodyContent = hdLClientPack;

Comment: try calling this instead `this.http.post(urlValue, hdLClientPack, new RequestOptions({headers: headers}))`

Comment: I tried this and still the same problem. Fiddler does not show any body content.